# when i use pyside-uic in win7, breakout and tell me :ImportError: No module named pkg_resources

Tags: python, pyside

When i use pyside-uic in win7, breakout and tell me:

```
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pyside-uic-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/).